# Dynamic React Router v4 Only Works in Same Directory as Routes declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

**I have the following tree structure:**

[image]

**And here is my code:**

```
const routes1 = [
    {path: '/home', loc: './home'},
    {path: '/about', loc: './about'},
    {path: '/contact', loc: './contact'}
];

const routes2 = [
    {path: '/home', loc: '../home'},
    {path: '/about', loc: '../about'},
    {path: '/contact', loc: '../contact'}
];

const routes3 = [
    {path: '/home', loc: '../home/index.js'},
    {path: '/about', loc: '../about/index.js'},
    {path: '/contact', loc: '../contact/index.js'}
];
```

---

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    {this.getRoutes()}
                    <Route component={NotFound}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }

    getRoutes() {
        const res = [];
        // components in same directory as app.js
        routes1.map((route, idx) => {
            res.push(<Route path={route.path} 
                        key={idx} 
                        component={require(`${route.loc}`).default} />)
        });
        return res;
    }
}
```

**The code above works when I point to components in the same directory as app.js when I map thru the array routes1**

However, mapping through either routes2 or routes3 I get this error:

[image]

[image]

Needless to say, the code for the related files are all the same in each directory, the only difference is their locations.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am not happy with this solution and I do not know why it is, but this works**

```
const routes2 = [
    {path: '/home', loc: 'home'},
    {path: '/about', loc: 'about'},
    {path: '/contact', loc: 'contact'}
];


................



getRoutes() {
    .............
    // I removed the '../' from the array and added it to the require statement
        res.push(<Route path={route.path} key={idx} component={require(`../${route.loc}`).default} />)
    });
    return res;
}
```

Someone tell me why I have to do it this way, I'd appreciate it.